# What's the meaning of "x" in RxD and TxD of UART?

Tags: uart

RxD means Receive Data.

TxD means Transmit Data.

Where the "x" come from?

Comment: Rx is short for receive because I guess someone decided it was easier than writing "receive" all the time. Likewise for Tx/transmit. It's not specific to electronics, you see e.g. pilots saying "pax" for "passengers".

Comment: This sort of word etymology question would probably be better on English.SE, in fact there's a related question that probably at least partially answers it: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229929/what-is-the-origin-of-tx-as-an-abbreviation-for-transaction/229934

Comment: I suspect the word "exchange" has something to do with it. See also PABX and MUX. But X could also mean "cross".

Comment: @PeterJ That's an unusually sparse answer for ESE. The use of x as an abbreviation is much older than the technological examples given. Consider Rx (for prescription, which is short for Latin recipe). This is different from the X in Xmas, where X is the first letter of the Greek spelling of Christ (Χριστός).

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37394/why-do-some-words-have-x-as-a-substitute

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comes from the 'good old days' of radio when Morse code ruled. Abbreviations abounded (c.f. text messages!), and TX was transmitter or transmit; RX was receiver or receive \$\cdot\cdot\cdot-\cdot-\$

Comment: "TT" or "RR" would be shorter in Morse code than "TX" or "RX". So why "X"? You might be right, but as a statement, this does not seem very compelling. One can argue whether etymology questions are suited for EE.SE, of course, but either way this is not an answer to such a question.

Comment: Try "beef essence" in Morse :-)